# Select Categories and count the Ads inside

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a query that select Categories name and count the max of Ads (active) in each category, I already did this:

```
SELECT
cat.cat_id,
cat.cat_desc,
COUNT(ad_id) AS cat_total_ads
FROM 
tab_categories AS cat LEFT JOIN
tab_ads AS ads ON ads.cat_id = cat.cat_id
WHERE
cat_active = @cat_active AND
cat_deleted = @cat_deleted
GROUP BY
cat_desc, cat.cat_id
```

This query is counting the non active Ads too. How can I put the value 0 for the non active Ads?

Comment: can you explain more regarding the column names? it's too undescriptive.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your setup is, but one trick you can do is `Sum(CASE WHEN Active THEN 1 ELSE 0)`, there is likely a better way but without knowing a little more it's hard to say.

Comment: @Jack It worked!!! Post your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use a combination of a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement to determine if you want to count the item and the [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) function.

For example

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Active THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

The SUM ( CASE  ..... then 1 else 0 end ) as colName  should do it for you !!

Try this i do not have the table to recreate to test but this or something similar should work.

```
select 
  cat.cat_id,
  cat.cat_desc,
  count(ad_id) as Total,
  sum(case when ad_id= 0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'ad_id'

from
  tab_categoriesAS cat LEFT JOIN
tab_ads AS ads ON ads.cat_id = cat.cat_id
WHERE
cat_active = @cat_active AND
cat_deleted = @cat_deleted
GROUP BY
cat_desc, cat.cat_id
```